# Python Logging - dictConfig - logging destination for sub modules

Tags: python, logging, socketserver

I have a python logging server, two test applications and one shared module (submod.py) I want both applications to be able to send log events to the server and have the server decide how to store them into separate log files. This is fairly easily until the shared module starts to log, I do not know how to allow the server to identify which program the sub module is sending log events for to store to the correct log file.

My logging server is a slightly modified version of the code I found [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/network-logging.html)

I tried to modify it to use a dictionary logging configuration similar to the following:

**test_log.conf**

```
"handlers": {
            "console": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "formatter": "complex",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
            },
            "test_01": {
                "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                "level": "INFO",
                "formatter": "complex",
                "filename": "test_01.log",
                "mode": "a",
                "backupCount": 5,
                "encoding": "utf8"
            },
            "test_02": {
                "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                "level": "INFO",
                "formatter": "complex",
                "filename": "test_02.log",
                "mode": "a",
                "backupCount": 5,
                "encoding": "utf8"
            },
            "file": {
                "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                "level": "INFO",
                "formatter": "complex",
                "filename": "root.log",
                "mode": "a",
                "backupCount": 5,
                "encoding": "utf8"
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "root": {
                "level": "INFO",
                "handlers": ["console", "file"]
            },
            "test_01":{
                "level": "INFO",
                "handlers": ["console", "test_01"]
            },
            "test_02": {
                "level": "INFO",
                "handlers": ["console", "test_02"]
            }
        }
```

**test_01.py**

```
main_logger = logging.getLogger('')
main_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)

main_logger.addHandler(socketHandler)

logging.info('Test 01 main program')

a = submod.SubClass()
```

**test_02.py**

```
main_logger = logging.getLogger('')
main_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)

main_logger.addHandler(socketHandler)

logging.info('Test 02 main program')

a = submod.SubClass()
```

**submod.py**

```
class SubClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.debug('Debug')
        log.info('Info')
        log.warn('Warning')
        log.error('Error')
        log.critical('Critical')
        print(__name__)
```

How can I have the logging server intelligently know where to log messages from submod.py when both test_01 and test_02 are calling it.

I apologize for formatting and the confusing explanation, the problem has caused brain-damage at this point for me.

**Edited:**
For clarity and re-wording a bad explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a config file where you can predefine the destination of your logging file based on the program that uses it. Python "logging" module accomplishes all the tasks you need; here is an example of a config file: http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/trunk/doc/html/logging-conf.html

Comment: As I understand the config you are referencing it does not solve the issue. I am trying to have a dynamic config that can apply to multiple programs that use the same submodules but have the server intelligently determine when a message from the submodules should be saved to each main program's log file.

Comment: Got it, how about this then? https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules

Comment: This could work, I was hoping to re-use the module between applications so statically assigning the parent is a little bit of a pain. Is there a way to determine the 'parent' that called or? Or should I just pass the name of the parent calling it as a variable and set it.

Comment: Write the logging module as a decorator and then all you need to do is add one line, @logging_module, to each one of your parents.